# what does "should it be" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The hemagglutinin,  which is also located in the viral coat, is the viral molecule recognised by the immune system.  Upon contact with it,  immune cells produce masses of antibodies,  which will protect the organism **should it be attacked by the virus again.**

What kind of meaning does "should it be" give in the context?

Answer (score 1):

It means the same as
*...which will protect the organism if it is attacked by the virus again.*